# Proxy software for all outgoing connection

Tags: c#, proxy, windows-server-2008, transparentproxy

I am working in an office, as our private requirements, we need to make all connection to specific domains must be sent via a proxy server. This is my issue for now, does anyone know a solution for this.

Anyone can show me a proxy software (a free software) that can support us to configure a list of proxy servers (we have proxy servers already) and a a list of specific domains?
If there is no such like proxy software, how can I implement a proxy like that using C#. I would like the proxy-aware will be done in system-level, NO application modification needed.

PS: I am using Windows server 2008

Thanks and best regards

Comment: It's called Linux. Specifically Squid and iptables. Also, off-topic, not programming... Another hint: google transparent proxy.

Comment: Your suggestion to implement a proxy is to move from windows to linux? Not very helpful.

Comment: @Rob. Bzzzz wrong assumption. Add a sub $50 piece of hardware on the network...

Comment: @Ieppie: Bzzz very unclear answer then...